# How do I add records to a DataGridView in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How do I add new record to DataGridView control in VB.Net?

I don't use dataset or database binding. I have a small form with 3 fields and when the user clicks OK they should be added to the DataGridView control as a new row.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to add the row to the end of the grid use the **Add()** method of the Rows collection...

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String(){Value1, Value2, Value3})
```

If you want to insert the row at a partiular position use the **Insert()** method of the Rows collection (as GWLlosa also said)...

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(rowPosition, New String(){value1, value2, value3})
```

I know you mentioned you weren't doing databinding, but if you defined a strongly-typed dataset with a single datatable in your project, you could use that and get some nice strongly typed methods to do this stuff rather than rely on the grid methods...

```
DataSet1.DataTable.AddRow(1, "John Doe", true)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should build a dataset/datatable in code and bind the grid to that.

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is 'Insert'.  It takes as its parameters the index you want to insert at, and an array of values to use for the new row values.  Typical usage might include:

```
myDataGridView.Rows.Insert(4,new object[]{value1,value2,value3});
```

or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to cast data source from datagridview that used bindingsource it error accor cannot casting:

----------Solution------------

'I changed casting from bindingsource that bind with datagridview

'Code here

```
Dim dtdata As New DataTable()

dtdata = CType(bndsData.DataSource, DataTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataSet`, you can not just add a new row in your `DataGridView` display. It will now work properly.

Instead you should add the new row in the `DataSet` with this code:

```
BindingSource[Name].AddNew()
```

This code will also automatically add a new row in your `DataGridView` display.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? My BindingSource has no method `AddNew()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use something that is more descriptive than a dumb array without resorting to using a DataSet then the following might prove useful. It still isn't strongly-typed, but at least it is checked by the compiler and will handle being refactored quite well.

```
Dim previousAllowUserToAddRows = dgvHistoricalInfo.AllowUserToAddRows
dgvHistoricalInfo.AllowUserToAddRows = True

Dim newTimeRecord As DataGridViewRow = dgvHistoricalInfo.Rows(dgvHistoricalInfo.NewRowIndex).Clone

With record
    newTimeRecord.Cells(dgvcDate.Index).Value = .Date
    newTimeRecord.Cells(dgvcHours.Index).Value = .Hours
    newTimeRecord.Cells(dgvcRemarks.Index).Value = .Remarks
End With

dgvHistoricalInfo.Rows.Add(newTimeRecord)

dgvHistoricalInfo.AllowUserToAddRows = previousAllowUserToAddRows
```

It is worth noting that the user must have `AllowUserToAddRows` permission or this won't work. That is why I store the existing value, set it to true, do my work, and then reset it to how it was.