# vb.net assigning stored procedure value as a new row to gridview

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, gridview, devexpress

I'm receiving data from stored procedure, but I dont know how to add it as new row to grid.

```
Dim SprocData As SelectedData = EUOW.ExecuteSprocParametrized("FinanceTool", New SprocParameter("@Years", ATBYears), New SprocParameter("@PlanningPeriodStartDate", StartDate.DateTime), New SprocParameter("@PlanningPeriodEndDate", EndDate.DateTime), New SprocParameter("@PerProduct", ValuesAsProduct), New SprocParameter("@Aggregation", Aggreg), New SprocParameter("@AggregationApplication", AggregApp), New SprocParameter("@AccountList", Accounts))

For Each StatementRow As SelectStatementResultRow In SprocData.ResultSet(0).Rows
                    StatementRow.Values
            Next
```

with value I can see the values but i don't know how to add them as new row to the gridview.

Sorry, I don't really know how to explain it exactly.

Hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks
Patryk

Comment: is it winforms?

Comment: yes, sorry forgot to mention, it is winforms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add records to a DataGridView in VB.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317567/how-do-i-add-records-to-a-datagridview-in-vb-net)

Comment: Hang on, you mention a GridView in the question title, but that is an ASP.NET thing. Your tags mention devexpress, which I think has an XtraGrid rather than a GridView. What sort of grid UI element are you actually using?

Comment: Andrew: The GridView is a WinForms component that is a part of the XtraGrid. The XtraGrid GridControl is simply a container for views, the most common being the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The common scenario of using grid control is displaying records from the specific data source, thus the best approach for adding new records is working with this data source directly rather than working via grid's methods.
So, if you need to add the resulting records set into "empty" grid or replace the existing one, you can just assign the grid's DataSource:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = SelectedData
```

Or, if you need to "append" data, you can add these data records into underlying data source directly:

```
' pseudo-code
gridControl1.DataSource = <Collection(Of Some Type)>
...
' after getting some results
<Collection(Of Some Type)>.AddRange(SelectedData)
```

In some scenario, you can add a new row using the [ColumnView.AddNewRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_AddNewRowtopic) method. This method is supposed to add a new "empty" row and then let the end-user fill its cell values manually. New record initialization can be performed manually by handling the [InitNewRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_InitNewRowtopic) event.
You can also initialize cell values in code using methods provided by the data source or the [ColumnView.SetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_SetRowCellValuetopic(Ex4JUg).aspx) method.

The [ColumnView.AddNewRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_AddNewRowtopic) method is effective only if grid's underlying data source supports the IBindingList interface.

Related help article: [Adding and Deleting Record](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument752)